# Autocompletar no funciona con jquery php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Este es el codigo que tengo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Al escribr dentro del input con id="pieza"
  $('#pieza').keypress(function() {
    //Obtenemos el value del input
    var pieza = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'pieza=' + pieza;

    //Le pasamos el valor del input al ajax
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "autocomplete.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(data) {
        //Escribimos las sugerencias que nos manda la consulta
        $('#suggestions').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
        //Al hacer click en algua de las sugerencias
        $('.suggest-element').live('click', function() {
          //Obtenemos la id unica de la sugerencia pulsada
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          //Editamos el valor del input con data de la sugerencia pulsada
          $('#pieza').val($('#' + id).attr('data'));
          //Hacemos desaparecer el resto de sugerencias
          $('#suggestions').fadeOut(1000);
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.suggest-element {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 350px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#suggestions {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" size="50" id="pieza" name="pieza" />
  <div id="suggestions"></div>
</form>
<?php $search=$ _POST[ 'pieza']; $query=$ db->query("SELECT nombre FROM piezas WHERE nombre like '" . $search . "%'" );
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { 
echo '
<div class="suggest-element">'.$row['nombre'].'</div>'; 
} ?>
```

el resultado de esto es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me muestra los dos registros y no me deja buscar ni autocompletar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero y aunque no tenga nada que ver es un poco peligroso el uso de variables POST o GET sin limpiar en cadenas de consulta a base de datos, pueden hacerte SQL INJECTION.

¿Tu problema puede ser que no le estés pasando el ID de la sugerencia?

```
<div class="suggest-element">'.$row['nombre'].'</div>';
```

¿Te falta algo como esto, no?

```
<div id="'.$row['id'].'" class="suggest-element">'.$row['nombre'].'</div>';
```

Porque tú dices

```
 //Obtenemos la id unica de la sugerencia pulsada
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Pero no seteas el ID nunca.